# Extracting specific nodes from an XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I want to read a section from the XML file below with C#.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" > 
 <DataSet>
 <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
 <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
 <xs:complexType>
 <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
 <xs:element name="Table">
 <xs:complexType>
 <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="Column1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
 <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
 <NewDataSet>
 <Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
  <Column1><Properties><Property>.....
```

I want to extract the nodes below the `Column1` nodes. The `Properties` node has lots of `Property` nodes, so I want the `Properties` node with all the `Property` nodes.

Please let me know the easiest and efficient way to get the nodes in C#.

Comment: What have you tried. Where are you stuck? Linq-to-XML is probably the easiest

Comment: I tried using XMLNodelist and then looping xml nodes but i want the easiest and efficient... can u give a sample of how it will be done in linq to xml?

Comment: Usually, you should show the gist of the code you're using right now so people can adapt that a little.

Comment: Your resultset will always be a nodelist, whatever method you use. If you want to do something with each one of those results, you can't get around looping through them. Also, the XML you posted is irrelevant up to `<Column1>` and what should be up there, isn't.

Comment: @wim my code is like    XMLData obj = new XMLData();
            DataSet dsXML = new DataSet();
            XmlDocument docXML = new XmlDocument();

            dsXML = obj.GetXML();
            XmlElement xE = (XmlElement)Serialize(dsXML);
            string strXml = xE.OuterXml.ToString();
            XElement xDoc = XElement.Parse(strXml);
            var properties = xDoc.XPathSelectElements("//Column1");

Comment: I have the nodes in properties. Now i  just want to get it into xelement or xmlelement so that i can use xelement.outerxml.tostring and load that string object to xmldocument object like xmldocobj.LoadXml(stringfrom_xlementobj) and return the value to the XMLDocument fcuntion . I want to do nothing with the nodes values , i just want to return the nodes as it is in XML format as i am using WCF service and wants to return the XML

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Linq-to-XML classes to parse the string and then XPath expression to select the nodes that you want:

```
XElement doc = XElement.Parse(s); //where s is a string containing the XML
var properties = doc.XPathSelectElements("//Column1/Properties");
```

Now `properties` contains a enumerable of the nodes that you want.

If you want to iterate through all the Property nodes you can do so like this:

```
foreach(var pp in properties)
{
    foreach(var p in pp.Elements("Property"))
    {
         //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: How can i just convert properties to XElement to load in the XMLDocument object? I have  a function which returns the XMLDocument and as i have got what i want in properties object, i want to just convert it into xlement.outerxml.ToString() and load the xmldocumnet object from it like docXML.LoadXml(xelementvariable.OuterXml.ToString()); and return the  value